# Get the largest Value from table unless null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to C# and ASP.NET (and programming in general) and try to do some simple exercises.

**What I am trying to do:**
I would like to build a simple MVC App where records will have versions.
That is: Given a record, that I am about to change via the "Edit"-View, this record will not be overwritten. Instead a new record will be created (like a new Version). Both, the old and new record, have the same ItemId (which is not the primary key!), that links them together "semantically". In order to know, which record is the newer Version, the newer record has a VersionId that is +1 the VersionId of the older one.

**Currently:** I've started working on the Create-Action. A new record shall get a value of 1 for it's VersionId and for ItemId the largest ItemId already in the DB plus 1 - unless there is no record in the DB in which case ItemId shall be 1.

**The Model:**

```
namespace HowToUpdate.Models
{
    public class ItemWithVersion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ItemNr { get; set; }
        public int VersionNr { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Controller Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] ItemWithVersion itemWithVersion)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // set the ItemNr
            int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);
            itemWithVersion.ItemNr = currentMaxItemNr + 1;

            // set the VersionNr
            itemWithVersion.VersionNr = 1;

            db.ItemWithVersions.Add(itemWithVersion);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(itemWithVersion);
    }
```

**Problem:** When I run `localhost/ItemWithVersion/Create`, enter a Value for the Name and Submit, i get the following error:
"The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. 
Source error: `int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);`"

**I tried:**

```
// set the ItemNr
int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);          
if (currentMaxItemNr == null)
{
    itemWithVersion.ItemNr = 1;
}
else
{
    itemWithVersion.ItemNr = currentMaxItemNr + 1;
}
```

Now the error seems to be `int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);`

Also `int? currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);` and `var currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);` won't do any good.

It's probably basic but I need your help! :) Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your table is not empty before calling the `Max()` method. You can use the `Any()` method to do that.

```
int currentMaxItemNr = 0;
if (db.ItemWithVersions.Any())
{
    currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);
}
itemWithVersion.ItemNr = currentMaxItemNr + 1;
// set the VersionNr
itemWithVersion.VersionNr = 1;

db.ItemWithVersions.Add(itemWithVersion);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to me to be the best solution. I do not need to change the model, the action keeps short and understandable. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your if-statement is wrong:

`if (currentMaxItemNr != null)`
currently checks if `currentMaxItemNr` has a value and if it does, make it `1`

So your statement should be `if (currentMaxItemNr == null)`

**Edit:**

I can't replicate your error unfortunately, but I did check and found out that there's an exception thrown when calling `Max()` on an empty `List`. So it would be better to first call `if (db.ItemWithVersions.Count() > 0)`

That way you are sure that `Max()` will return a result. If it fails that statement, you can set `currentMaxItemNr` to `0`

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the reason is that Id is declared as a int (not nullable, so null can not be assigned to id) .
 Try following.

```
 public int? Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! You solved it! :)  At first, I have set `public int? ItemId {get; set;}`. Now VisualStudio tells me "Cannot convert source type 'System.Nullable<int>' to target type 'int' ". So I change `int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);` to `int? currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr);`. Now it works! :D

Comment: @roxxistic Happy if that was useful ))

Comment: @roxxistic little bit sugar
`int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr) ?? 1;`

Comment: The problem with this solution is: I need to define ItemId as nullable. This does not make sense much, since it never should be null in the DB. Therefore I change to the Answer by @Shyju.

Answer (score 0):

Care to try?

```
int currentMaxItemNr = db.ItemWithVersions.Max(i => i.ItemNr ?? 1);
```

This will return `currentMaxItemNr = 1` if your `i.ItemNr` is **null**.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I have tried, but complier returns an error: "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int' ". VisualStudio says "Left operand of the '??' operator should be of reference or nullable type".

Answer (score 0):

here is how I would do this. When you click on Edit we run:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] ItemWithVersion itemWithVersion)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // get the item with highest version
        ItemWithVersion item = db.ItemWithVersions.Where(i =>i.ItemNr == itemWithVersion.ItemNr).OrderByDescending(i => i.VersionNr).FirstOrDefault();
        //if item doesnt exist we need to create
        if(item == null)  {
           //get the last item with highest ItemNr
           ItemWithVersion lastitem = db.ItemWithVersions.OrderByDescending(i => i.ItemNr).FirstOrDefault();
           if(lastitem == null) {
             //if we didnt find a item, it means is the first item in the DB
             itemWithVersion.ItemNr = 1;
           } else {
             //increment the itemNr for the new Item
             itemWithVersion.ItemNr = lastitem.ItemNr + 1;
           }
           //set version to 1 since is the first version for this new ItemNr
           itemWithVersion.VersionNr = 1;
        } else {
            //if we found a item for the current ItemNr we increase the version for the new item
           itemWithVersion.VersionNr = item.VersionNr + 1;
        }

        db.ItemWithVersions.Add(itemWithVersion);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(itemWithVersion);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! It seems to be legit, but also more work for the controller / database to do, if it shall select and order from the table. Max seems to me to be a more efficient way. However I do not know what actually is done by the server in those cases and which one really takes more effort. That is the reason I chose the answer of Shyju.